# Including publications on CV if none are peer-reviewed

Tags: publications, cv, review-articles

I'm updating my CV and need advice regarding publications.  I am formerly a Professor of Human Services and Counselor Education.  I am not currently in academia, but am a licensed counselor in private practice... just updating the CV to be prepared for possible future opportunities.

I have written articles for publication in magazines, newspapers, and online resources (blogs, etc.) for 13 years or more.  I've also been quoted as an "expert" in numerous articles that other folks have written... some are national publications for our profession.

I do not have any peer reviewed journal articles at all.

1. Should I list the articles for newspapers, magazines, blogs, etc. that I have written on my CV?  Assuming APA style if so. Under what heading shall I list them so it is not confused with academic publications?
2. How do I list articles in which I have been quoted by another author?  Under what heading shall I list them? I've not had any luck with my research on this one.

Comment: While North Americans use the words "CV" and "resume" differently, non-North Americans generally use "CV" for both (though they may distinguish  between a "full CV" and a "brief CV").  Please clarify.

Comment: I strongly suspect answers to this question will depend not only upon academic subfield but also the kind of "future opportunity" you are talking about.  A department offering a doctoral degree in your subject may have a different view than a department focused on training future practitioners at the undergraduate level.

Comment: HI Alexander,  in the mental health field, resumes seem to suffice.  I am currently working on a full CV... just wanting to do this the right way without offending academics.....

Comment: I have experience as a professor, adjunct and program director in the college systems, but the majority of my experience has been in the counseling field (private and community agency).  So, I'm compiling everything I have accomplished into one document... a full CV....

Comment: Typically, in an academic CV, you don't list articles from other authors which cite you or quote you.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I think the question is, how to list cited non-peer reviewed papers of OP.

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek Point 2 of the question is about listing articles from _other_ authors.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano As far as I understood it was papers of OP that were cited by other authors that were to be included, and not the papers of other others that cite OP.

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek The OP says "How do I list articles _in which_ [...]": to me this means that she wants to list the articles in which quotes from her articles appear. It's not very clear, though, and a clarification from the OP would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would put all of the non-academic writing you've done under a heading like "Other Writing for a Popular Audience". Beware that such publications won't count for much in applying for faculty jobs, or at least, that they won't replace peer-reviewed academic research. However, they might be a "value-add" at some places.

You never list in the CV where you've been cited. (At least not that I've ever seen). Instead, what I see people do is mention their citations as a single line in the cover letter. "My work has been cited in prestigious venues like *The Journal of X Studies* and *X Studies Review.*"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "Magazines" or "Publications (not peer reviewed)".

If my research is covered in the news, then I list the article under a section "Media" using APA format. I do not recommend mentioning academic citations.

Answer (score 0):

Some opinions are field specific and not representative of all academics.  There are many types of disciplines and conventions within them, even with a CV.  This means there is both a precedent for what you are asking, and also the inevitable disagreement from someone in another area on the value.

You can list non peer reviewed papers in a category as you choose.  Some examples:

- Authored Publications
- Publications (non-reviewed)
- Magazine Publications

Likewise, you can refer to articles that cite/mention you as

- Media
- Cited
- Publications on Work

For reference, academics in design fields will use this style and do exactly as you are asking.  [Here is just one example.](https://taubmancollege.umich.edu/sites/default/files/pdfs/faculty/mpdl-cv.pdf)